# Ionic Zip folder structure

Tags: xml, vb.net, zip

I am trying to add some zipping code to my program, however, i can't seem to get the folder structure just right.

I want the folder to look like this:

```
Root (
   -subfolder1
   -subfolder2
   individual file
   individual file
   individual file)
```

So, the indidivual files will be in the root folder of the zip and the folders that i add will become subfolders to the root. my code is below....

```
Using zip As New ZipFile()
    For Each item As System.Xml.XmlNode In Source
        If item.InnerText.Contains(".") Then
            zip.AddFile(item.InnerText)
        Else
            zip.AddDirectory(item.InnerText, GetLastDirName(item.InnerText))
        End If
    Next

    For Each item As System.Xml.XmlNode In Destin
        Dim path As String = item.InnerText
        zip.Save(path.Replace(".zip", "") & "_Archive_" & DateString & ".zip")
    Next
End Using
```

however, the `zip.addfile(item.innertext)` line addes the individual files to the full path. So, if the file is `C:\Pictures\image.jpg` ...it will appear as such in the zip file, with all the subfolders.

I have also tried things like `zip.addfile(item.innertext, "individual files")` to create a folder for just individual files...but meh, i want those files to be stored in the root.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the method AddFile, there are two parameters you can pass in:

1. The file name
2. The directory path in archive.

The Ionic documentation states that for that second parameter, the rules are as follows:

> Specifies a directory path to use to override any path in the
>   fileName. This path may, or may not, correspond to a real directory in
>   the current filesystem. If the files within the zip are later
>   extracted, this is the path used for the extracted file. Passing null
>   (Nothing in VB) will use the path on the fileName, if any. Passing the
>   empty string ("") will insert the item at the root path within the
>   archive.

Source (http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/202e1fb5-8891-888f-8e91-1340f7cd80c9.htm)

The means that in your code above, where you pass in only the first parameter (file name), you will use the full path off of the file you're adding.  Add the path you want to the AddFile method as your second parameter, and you're good to go.